# Is there a way to set up a PoS private blockchain

Tags: private-blockchain, eth-2.0

I am tryiong to set a PoS eth v2 private blockchain using geth and prysm
I ve been trying lots of different things but do not mange to extend the working example I found : https://github.com/OffchainLabs/eth-pos-devnet/blob/master/README.md to make it work with several nodes on several servers.
In addition this seems to work when you launch it once but you can not stop and restart the service (you need to restart from a clean blockchain). So it is not suitable for production.
Has anybody already set a private PoS Blcockain ?

Thanks
PS : do not answer use ETH v1 Pow or Clique .. that I know how to do and is not what I am looking for

Comment: Have you tried using HyperLeger Besu?

Comment: as stated I want eth v2... so getting besu is not an option